# Encrypting Parameters in URLs

Tags: java, url, get, jasperserver

I have a URL that looks like this:

http://localhost:8001/jasperserver&reportUnit=somereport&username=cghan&**password=somepasswrd**

As you can see, the password is in clear site, along with some other parameters.

What's the best way to secure this?

Comment: Where does this URL come from? From a link? From a form submit? From a redirect? Etc.

Answer (score 2):

Set the method of the FORM (in HTML) to POST. That way attributes won't be shown in the URL (they can be retrieved exactly the same way).

Anyway, for anyone with a sniffer, it will make little difference. If it is really important, force the server to use only HTTPS.

Comment: Agreed that using POST is better.  Even with HTTPs, the URLs are shown to anyone who looks at your web server access log files.  POST gets that info out of the URL.

Answer (score 2):

Use SSL encryption, i.e. HTTPS. This makes it encrypted for everyone on the internet but it is still readable on the address bar.

It is not recommended to send password parameters through URL, e.g. HTTP POST. You should send password as HTTP POST.