# Create a single link having encrypted username/password for logging into a website

Tags: c#, asp.net, web

I am developing an ASP.NET application that requires a username and password to login. I wish to invite a set of users who will login into to the site and use the application . However, I do not want to send the username and password separately, but instead send a single link ( which will be generated automatically by the application and which will have an encrypted version of the username/password in it. The username and password for this user is stored in the database. clicking on the link will automatically log the user into the application. I have seen this behavior with some web applications but am not sure how this can be achieved. Any help is appreciated.

thanks
kabir

Comment: Is this on an intranet/internet application?  How sensitive is the data?

Comment: Do you use SSL? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11027708/include-an-encrypted-password-in-a-url-possible

Comment: possible duplicate of [Encrypting Parameters in URLs](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5533162/encrypting-parameters-in-urls)

Comment: Along the lines of @Moo-Juice comment - so _anyone_ with the link can login as "that" user (any time)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public static class SecurePassword
{

    #region Fields

    static byte[] _entropy = System.Text.Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes("Db Config Password");

    #endregion

    #region Methods


    public static SecureString GetSecureString(string password)
    {
        SecureString secureString = new SecureString();

        foreach (char c in password)
        {
            secureString.AppendChar(c);
        }

        secureString.MakeReadOnly();
        return secureString;
    }


    public static string GetInsecureString(SecureString securePassword)
    {
        string password = string.Empty;

        IntPtr ptr = System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.SecureStringToBSTR(securePassword);

        try
        {
            password = System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.PtrToStringBSTR(ptr);
        }
        finally
        {
            System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ZeroFreeBSTR(ptr);
        }

        return password;
    }


    public static string EncryptString(SecureString securePassword)
    {
        byte[] encryptedData = System.Security.Cryptography.ProtectedData.Protect(
                System.Text.Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(GetInsecureString(securePassword)),
                _entropy,
                System.Security.Cryptography.DataProtectionScope.CurrentUser);

        return Convert.ToBase64String(encryptedData);

    }


    public static SecureString DecryptString(string encryptedData)
    {
        try
        {
            byte[] decryptedData = System.Security.Cryptography.ProtectedData.Unprotect(
                Convert.FromBase64String(encryptedData),
                _entropy,
                System.Security.Cryptography.DataProtectionScope.CurrentUser);

            return GetSecureString(System.Text.Encoding.Unicode.GetString(decryptedData));
        }
        catch
        {
            return new SecureString();
        }
    }

    #endregion


}
```

This is the class for encryp/Decrypt.

Here how to use it:

```
string ecryptPass = BO.SecurePassword.EncryptString(BO.SecurePassword.GetSecureString(password));
string decryptPass = BO.SecurePassword.GetInsecureString((BO.SecurePassword.DecryptString(encrypedRequestParamPassword)));
```

Create page LinkLogin.aspx when you go to the page read the Request parameters and decrypt the password/username in the page load and redirect it to the wanted page with user credentials.

Comment: What is `getLastValidConnectionNode["Password"].InnerText`? How much secure is using symmetric encryption this way?

Comment: @VDohnal sorry I copy this from one my test project, I will edit it.

Comment: Did you think about the problem, that encrypting a password in URL like this actually does not solve anything except hiding the user's password from the user himself?

Comment: @VDohnal this is the goal of the op, he want to send a link to the user with encrypted pass and user name, after clicking the link decrypt the password in LinkLogin.aspx.

Comment: Right, but I do not think @kabir is aware of all the pitfalls of this approach. As it is written in the link in comments `the encrypted password has become the password`.

Comment: We can let the user know of the password later by other means as well ( eg. when he has logged in, he can change his password and the next time he has to use the usual username/password combination to login.) This approach will be used probably the first time only to help the user login easily.

Comment: But  it is completely pointless to do this type of encryption. It does not add any security to your app compared to plain text password in URL.

Comment: @kabir It would be safer and more logical to use SSL and to create temporary password that must be changed after the first login.